# How to plot sin(x) + sin(y) = 1 in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the parametric function `sin(x) + sin(y) = 1`, but I'm not quite there yet. Here's my script:

```
set parametric

set urange [-10:10]
set vrange [-10:10]
set sample 2000
set size ratio -1
set grid front
unset border

splot sin(u) + sin(v) = 1
```

But I get the error: `line 10: parametric function not fully specified`. What should I do? I want my function plotted as Desmos does it, in the Cartesian coordinate system:

[image]

Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: When using `set parametric` you have to give `plot` in a pair, and `splot` as a triplet. As an example `plot x, y` or  `splot x, y, z` I'm not entirely sure if your plotting of the equation is valid but you're basically saying `splot x` and disregarding the y and z, which is why it's giving you that error. How to do what you're wanting? I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for the tip! In this case, I only disregarded `y`, because I don't need `z` (I'm plotting in 2D space). So I'll definitely use `plot` and not `splot`.

Answer (score 2):

`sin(x) + sin(y) = 1` is not a [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) but an [implicit equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function). Either you need to do some maths and find a corresponding parametric equation, or you need to resort to a 'trick' which is the one you've probably used in Desmos: gnuplot can plot [isolines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) of functions, so you can plot the isoline 1 of `f(x,y)=sin(x) + sin(y)`.

```
set cntrparam levels discrete 1
set contour
set view map
unset surface
set isosample 100
splot sin(x)+sin(y)
```